# Oncompletion Listener in android Media player

Tags: java, android

I want to play MediaPlayer one after other, i can able to get first file but could not able to get remaining files...

whether this code is correct...

```
private void playRecording()  {

    player = new MediaPlayer();

    player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            player.stop();
            if (i < numberOfFiles) {

                i++;
                playAudio(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath()
                        + "/android"
                        + i
                        + ".3gp");
            }else i=0;
        }


    });
    player.start();
```

playAudio:

```
  private void playAudio(String filename) {
      try {
      player.setDataSource(filename); 
      player.prepare();
      player.start();
  } catch (Exception e) { 
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace(); 
      } 
      }
```

Comment: Any error in log cat?

Comment: no error in log cat..i am getting but audio correctly but it is not going to second audio..

Comment: it is methodeprivate void playAudio(String filename) {

  try {

   player.setDataSource(filename);
   player.prepare();
   player.start();

  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Comment: Within playAudio function print filename and check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `OnCompletionListener` with following:

```
player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            if (i < numberOfFiles) {
                i++;
 String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() .getAbsolutePath()+ "/android"+"/"+i+".3gp";
           playAudio(path);
            }
            else i=0;
        }
```

Comment: Because as @sssvrock said you should use reset() in place of release.

Answer (score 3):

In place of calling `mp.release();` It's better to call `mp.reset();`

where release will releases the object and reset is like just creating the object.

Comment: Please do not add comments on answers as answer.